# How get Audio files of mp3 format from media store api?

Tags: android, mediastore

I'm using Media store api to fetch all audio files on device storage. But problem is that it's also collecting ring tones of format .ogg. How filter to only collect mp3 format files. This is how i'm collecting files

```
val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            arrayOf(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID),
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + "=? ",
            arrayOf(filePath), null
        )
```

Comment: .MIME_TYPE.....